# Android: использование библиотеки в приложении без соответсвующей лицензии

Tags: android

Есть одна библиотека, использование которой бесплатно при условии, что приложение не загружено в google play.

Возник вопрос: может ли google play что-то предъявить мне?

Это же придется в коде обфусцированного APK кому-то копаться, чтобы выкатить иск.

Или можно смело пользоваться и сэкономить 3000$ не боясь попасть под бан?

**PS: Всё законно - исходные коды библиотеки открыты и под лицензией GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE, чего вы минусуете?
Не смотря на GPL авторы почему-то запрещают использовать в коммерческих продуктах и продают .jar файлом это всё.**

Конечно, бонусом идет поддержка 24/7, но к чему тогда запрет - не понятно.

Если исходный код приложения в котором применяется либа под GPL v3 открыт - то проблем нет.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что правовые вопросы не по теме ресурса.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, Здесь люди опытом делятся, а не занудничают! Лишь бы что-то закрыть, да запретить.

Comment: @Evgeniy, да, вполне могут предъявить, возможно не только google play, но и автор библиотеки.

Comment: Скорее даже Google Play сам ничего не предъявит, а вот автор библиотеки очень даже может, и одним и средств воздействия может быть DMCA takedown в GP, в результате которого приложение пропадёт из магазина, и вернуть его обратно будет непросто.

Comment: А после пары таких инцидентов могут и аккаунт заблокировать.

Comment: @Evgeniy, классный опыт: я украду $3k, меня поймают? :-D Вы хотя бы потрудились вопрос нейтрально и технически задать.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, все всё поняли и лучший ответ уже найден.

Comment: @Evgeniy после таких комментариев я первый накатаю разработчику либы и скажу, чтобы он обратил особое внимание.

Comment: @Peter Samokhin, какой либы? GPL V3, и у меня GPL V3, куда ты собрался катать?) Придержи лошадей! Без обид.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Тут дело не только в бане. На вас могут подать в суд и отсудить значительно больше стоимости использования, в зависимости от составленного договора. По сути при использовании проприетарных библиотек вы соглашаетесь на данный договор и правообладателям уже не составит труда подтвердить данный факт его нарушения в суде.

Такие компании, которые разрабатывают библиотеки с их продажей за 3000$, мне кажется могут позволить себе несколько специалистов по реверс-инжинирингу, для выяснения, использована ли данная библиотека в вашем коде.

Совершенно другой вопрос, как вообще будут обстоять дела, действия компаний на этот счёт непредсказуемы, с одной стороны не факт, что ваше приложение станет настолько популярным, что правообладатели библиотеки станут его исследовать, но чем чёрт не шутит, возможно и ситуация, что даже если оно не станет популярным, на вас могут подать иск.

Comment: Лучший ответ! Лицензия там GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE, исходники открыты. При этом запрещают заливать в маркет приложение с их либой. Очень странно.

Comment: А вот это интересная поправка, по GPL можно устанавливать плату за использование библиотеки, однако нельзя обязать пользователей платить за её использование ну и следует учитывать, что скорее всего часть или вся ваша программа тоже должна соответствовать GPL. Но эти вопросы уже слишком трудны, фигня определяется на глаз, в каждом конкретном случае надо разбираться отдельно.

Comment: Да, с этой лицензией всё не просто: можно открыть код приложения, который использует эту либо под GPL V3 и проблем не будет. При этом открыв часть кода неизбежно потребуется открыть и остальной код, в котором используется этот :)

Comment: Да, так и есть.